# How to avoid repeatedly adding the checked value to the input text box

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on a project where I want to add the radio button value to the input field.

The input field is to add a name, and radio button is used to select the sex. By default it should be "My Name" on the input field, and when the user checks the radio button, it should add the text "I am a {radio button value}".

I've managed to do some of this, but the problem is:

1. When I switch the radio button it keeps on adding the text, and it looks silly.
2. By default it shows the value "I am a undefined" where it should be "my Name"
3. How can I validate that the user has selected the sex when they submit?

```
 <input type="radio" id="single" name="sex" value="Boy">Boy &nbsp;  &nbsp; |  &nbsp;&nbsp; 
 <input type="radio" id="single" name="sex" value="Girl">Girl     
 <br><br><br><br>
 <p></p>
```

Jquery Script

```
function displayVals() {
var a = $("input[type='radio']:checked").val();
var b = "I am a";

var checkedValue = $( "p" ).html( "<b>I am a </b> " + " " + a );

var input = $("input[type='text']");
input.val(input.val() + b + " " + a);

}

$( "input[type='radio']" ).change( displayVals );
displayVals();
```

Link to the fiddle example is

http://jsfiddle.net/ssbrbsfp/2/

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ssbrbsfp/6/

To avoid duplicate result, don't reappend the input.val in it :

```
input.val(b + " " + a);
```

Check if the value is undefined before filling the input and the p :

```
if(a != undefined)
{
    $( "p" ).html( "<b>I am a </b> " + " " + a );
    var input = $("input[type='text']");
    input.val(b + " " + a);
}
else
{
    $( "p" ).html( "<b>I am a </b> ");
}
```

To validate before submit :

```
$(".SubmitButton").click(function () {
    if($("input[type='radio']:checked").val() == undefined)
    {

        alert("You must choose a sex");
        return false;
    }
});
```

I put it on the submit button to show you the behavior but you should put it in the form submit event.

Comment: thanks, its works great. However I would like to allow user to type their name and then select the sex. so it will be "Isqware" and "I am a boy"

Comment: Thansk Mathieu, But after typing my name in the text box when i click the sex radio button it delete my name and populate the input text field with "I am a Boy/I am a Girl" I would like to keep the name as well. Thanks for you help and effort.

Answer (score 0):

First you execute the function `displayVals();` on dom ready without a radio is selected so the input  text get the vaule of undefined. Second you add the old value everytime on radio change. Take a look here:

```js
function displayVals() {
  var a = $("input[type='radio']:checked").val();
  var b = "I am a";

  var checkedValue = $("p").html("<b>I am a </b> " + " " + a);

  var input = $("input[type='text']");
  //you want to add only the value of radio each time.
  input.val(a);

}

$("input[type='radio']").change(displayVals);
//why execute this one on dom ready??
//displayVals();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" onblur="this.placeholder = 'my name'" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" placeholder="my name" name="name" id="my name" class="InputText">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="SubmitButton">

<br>

<input type="radio" id="single" name="sex" value="Boy">Boy &nbsp; &nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" id="single" name="sex" value="Girl">Girl

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<p></p>
<select id="single">
  <option>Single</option>
  <option>Single2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, there are several things:

1. Remove the `onblur` and `onfocus` from the input text definition, `placeholder` already behaves like that.
2. Remove the call to `displayVals()` at the end of the script
3. Remove the `input.val() +` in the reassignation of the input.val
4. For the validation, you may add the keyword `required` to the definition of either `input radio` tags, or even both.